# Jtree node expansion without selection

Tags: java, jtree

Is it possible to expand/collapse a node in a JTree without having it selected? (not highlighted)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to expand/collapse each node you care to by using the expand or collapse method.  Here's a good example on javaalmanac.

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.tree/ExpandAll.html